# What are the exact settings which control if the Pages library and Documents library are rendered in Classic or in New experience

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, office-365, modern-experience

I have a team site collection inside my sharepoint online tenant, which i have migrated from sharepoint on-premises 2013. but i am a bit confused on how we can control if our pages library and our document library are rendered in Classic experience or in New experience.

- On the tenant i defined the following:-

[image]

- On all the document and pages libraries i have the following setting under Advance settings:-

[image]

Now the result i got inside my sites are:-

1. If i access site home page `/SitePages/Home.aspx,`, which contain a web part for my document library,the home page it will be rendered in classic experience.:-

[image]

2. while if i click on the document library itself `/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx` it will be rendered in New experience :-

[image]

So not sure why the `AllItems.aspx` is being rendered in modern experience, while `home.aspx` is being rendered in classic experience..??

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is some feature enabled on home page that is incompatible with the new UI.  It auto-detects when there are unsupported features in place and automatically uses the classic experience even if the setting is for the new experience.  Here's an article that details the unsupported features.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-the-new-document-library-experience-and-classic-mode-30e1aab0-a5cc-4363-b7f2-09e2ae07d4dc?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#BKMK_AutoDetectFeatures

Comment: thanks for the reply. but i have some `home.aspx` pages, which do not have any thing inside them, and i did not customize them,, but those migrated `home.aspx`  are being rendered in classic mode..

Answer (score 1):

Though you have set the default experience as new experience , it will not support for this Document App Part . The settings you have set is only for lists or libraries .  You can only display these app part on a modern page .

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-document-library-web-part-a9dfecc3-2050-4528-9f00-2c5afc5731b0 .

Comment: thanks for the reply. now on the `home.aspx` i removed the document library web part, but still this `home.aspx` will be rendered in classic mode, regardless of the settings on the Pages library and on the tenant level... also i have other `home.aspx` page which did not have any web part inside it,, but still this `home.aspx` will be rendered in classic mode also.. not sure what is going on ???